# $z=( (y⋅x)⋅0.002)+(y⋅x) $ and solve for $ x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for such a basic question, but it has been a very long time since my high school math classes. Given the equation
$z = ( (y \cdot x) \cdot  0.002) + (y \cdot  x) $

how could I solve for $x$ if I know $y$ and $z$? Thanks.

Comment: Matt, what is your *? Do you mean exponentiation or is it multiplication? In the latter case $x=\frac{z}{1.002y}$

Comment: multiplication. sorry, I spend too much time writing C code

Comment: OK no pb - do you see how to get to the answer I gave?

Comment: yep, thanks a lot. if you want the points just repost it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$z = ( (y \cdot x) \cdot  0.002) + (y \cdot  x) \Leftrightarrow z=(y \cdot x)(1 \cdot 0.002 + 1) \Leftrightarrow z=x \cdot y \cdot (1.002) \Leftrightarrow x=\frac{z}{1.002 \cdot y}$